# Restrict opening .xls files with notepad

Tags: asp.net, export-to-excel

I need to restrict users from opening an Excel (.xls) file with notepad.

I have an application that exports data into .xls format. Now when I open the generated file with notepad I am able to see the contents clearly but if I open a normal excel file with notepad it will show the contents in "corrupted" format.

How can I make the contents of the generated xsl file appear "corrupted" when opened with notepad?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are not writing a (binary) Excel file, but a CSV (text) file that you give a .xls extension. Excel will open that fine, but Notepad also.

What you need to do is write a *real* Excel file. I've has some success using [ExcelLibrary](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/). But also some issues: make sure the resulting file is at least 7k in size, by appending empty rows.

Comment: Of course the user could just save the file as .csv and open it in notepad. :)

Answer (score 2):

No! That is not possible. On client-side user can open a document in any application he/she wants.

Comment: He's not trying to prevent the user from opening the file in Notepad, but rather to not allow the data to be readable as plain-text.

Answer (score 1):

Once the file is on the client side he can and will do anything with it, you cannot do anything because your asp.net application is running on a remote server that does not have full access to the client machine due to security concerns, even if( a pretty big if) you some how manage to do this, the user will just copy the file to another system or simply close his browser.